# Adding Spaces Between Images

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment and I do not know how to add spacing between my images. I need to create a style rule that sets the right and bottom padding of the div element with the ID container to 8 pixels.

For every a element within a div element belonging to the cell class, create a style rule to display the hypertext link as a block with a width of 100% and set the left and top padding to 8 pixels.

```
div#container {

  padding-right: 8px;

  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

div[class^="cell"]>a {

  display: block;

  width: 100%;

  padding-left: 8px;

  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

This is what I have and it says it is wrong. I have also tried changing `div[class^="cell"]` to `div[.class^="cell"]` and `div[class="cell"]` and also `div[#class^="cell"]` but none of them work.

Do you see any mistakes or anything I can change?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I will definitely do that next time.Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CSS, I would expect your HTML to look something like this.
The following code works with the CSS

```css
div#container {
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

div[class^="cell"]>a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell_1">
    <a href="#">Sample Line here</a>
    <a href="#">Have another line</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cell_2">
    <a href="#">Here is a third line in a separate cell</a>
    <a href="#">Have a fourth line</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I don't know what HTML you're using, lets talk about what your CSS is suggesting.
`div#container` looks for a `<div>` tag containing an id of container: `<div id="container">`.

`div[class^="cell"]>a` has a couple things going on. Understand that any time your selector has brackets `[]`, we're selecting based on an attribute. In this case, you make it clear that we're looking for a class attribute. The `^=` indicates that the attribute should begin with the provided characters.

Therefore, `div[class^="cell"]` on its own would select all div elements that contain a class starting with the characters "cell". Therefore div elements with classes of `.cell`, `.cell_1`, `.cell_3`, `.cellular` would all be matched.

The `>` character in your selector looks for immediate child elements.

In this code example:

```
<div class="cell_1">
  <a>Sample Line Here</a>
  <div>
    <a>Have another line</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

"Sample Line Here" would be matched because it is an immediate child of `.cell_1`
"Have another line" is nested in another div element, so it would not get your custom styles.

`div[class^="cell"]>a` would translate more literally to select

**all `<a>` tags that are immediate children of a `<div>` tag that contain a class attribute that begins with the characters 'cell'**

If you are using the class `.cell`, rather than classes which start with "cell", you could replace `div[class^="cell"] > a` with `div.cell > a` or `.cell > a`. If you also don't need to target direct descendants, you might try seeing if `.cell a` does the trick. That would target all `<a>` tags inside of any element with the class "cell".

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, please add HTML to your question, so we can help you troubleshoot a little more thoroughly. This CSS Selectors Reference from w3 schools is fantastic: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try it real fast and get back to you :)

Comment: Also, I'm trying to build reputation. If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it for me. If it wasn't helpful, let me know so I can improve it ^.^

Comment: Awe, I tried to upvote it but it says I don't have enough reputation :/